# Troubleshooting printing in landscape mode

Tags: printing, adobe-acrobat, dot-matrix-printer

I have trouble figuring out how to set the print settings to be able to print in landscape mode.

I have ~A3 paper which is fed, in landscape orientation, to a A3 dot matrix printer (the printer has single feed tray which accepts all formats). I've created a sample ~A3 size pdf to test if it prints correctly, but no matter which settings I choose, it prints incorrectly.

I've created two paper sizes (Variant A and Variant B) with paper dimensions 377x279 and 279x377 respectively and tried printing in both portrait and landscape orientations using both variants (4 distincts attempts in total) but every attempt leads to the same, incorrect results.

The printer driver is OKI ML321 PPD and the print is performed through CUPS IPP, so `adobe -> generic PS -> ipp -> cups -> ML321 PPD -> printer`.

I belive it's easier to explain using images so...

That's the paper feed orientation and sample file

[image]

and my paper size variants

[image]

the expected printout is

[image]

the actual printout is

[image]

As you can see, no matter which settings I choose, the printout always ends up on two sheets. The `Variant A - landscape/Variant B - portrait` would be the correct one, but for some reason either the printer(?) or Adobe(?) rotates the print 90 degrees so it ends up on two sheets instead of one.

Comment: Is the issue *only* with Adobe, or also when printing from other apps?